# Convert date (PHP)

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am using [`JDF` library](https://jdf.scr.ir/download/tabdil_dl.php) for converting databases dates in my panel. My programming language is `php` and i am using `while` loop for show data. database date type is `datetime`.For example : ***2018-07-21 11:14:19.678896***

```
<?php
Include_once "jdf.php";
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $array = explode(' ', $row['date']);
    list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $array[0]);
    list($hour, $minute, $second) = explode(':', $array[1]);
    $timestamp = mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year);
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tehran");
    $converted_date = jdate("Y/m/d H:i:s", $timestamp);
    echo $row['full_name'] . ", reg date:" . $converted_date;
}
```

When i run code, `Y/m/d` become convert *BUT* for `H:i:s` **just first row** become convert. I really dont know why ... 
Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably simpler to use the inbuilt [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class to process your data:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $date = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', $row['date'], new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    $date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Tehran'));
    $converted_date = jdate('Y/m/d H:i:s', (int)$date->format('U'));
    echo $row['full_name'] . ", reg date:" . $converted_date;
}
```

Output:

```
2018/07/21 15:44:19
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/MkRSD)

Comment: Thanks, But i wan to show my country date, i dont want for example 2018/07/21.want 1397/04/16.

Comment: so jdf library is for this work

Comment: @O.Hebaby My edited code will now call `jdate`, it uses `$date->format('U')` to get the timestamp from the adjusted date

Comment: output is : 1543046922

Comment: Thanks its works But i dont know why in some rows it add 3:30 in other 5:30 and some times 2:30

Comment: @O.Hebaby it is probably related to daylight savings time. The time difference between Tehran and UTC will change according to the time of year. Although it is strange that it could be `5:30`